# Web Request using python dectected as automated

Tags: python, web, request

Here is the code, it's for a SEO project I am working on:

```
import urllib, urllib2, re

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

def check_account(email, password, cookie):
    header = {'Cookie': 't=%s;js_csrf=%s;' % (cookie,cookie), 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    data = {'t': cookie, 'login_email': email, 'login_password': password, 'lhs_type': 'default', 'display': 'desktop'}

    try:
        req = urllib2.Request('https://www.dropbox.com/ajax_login', urllib.urlencode(data), header)
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except:
        return False

    read = resp.read()

    return read

resp = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://www.dropbox.com/login', None))
cookie = re.findall(r't=(.*?);', str(resp.info()))[0]

resp_data = check_account('random@email.com','random', cookie)

print resp_data
```

Here is the reponse:

```
err:{"login_email": {"message_html": "We didn\u0026rsquo;t allow this login because it appeared to be automated. Please contact \u003ca href='/support'\u003eDropbox support\u003c/a\u003e if you believe this was a mistake."}}
```

Comment: So what do you want us to do? We don't know what Dropbox does to detect automated logins. And if they are going to these lengths to try and prevent automated logins, have you checked if the terms of service perhaps disallow such automation?

Comment: i think its to do with accessing the ajax page directly because i tried stalling the request in tamper data and it works yet it didnt in live http headers. I am not using this for anything that breaks their TOS I am making a website for something to do with dropbox am just currently working in python atm but will port it into php later"

Comment: Better use the [Dropbox API for Python](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python)